# OfficeJS read old .doc file

Tags: javascript, ms-word, ms-office, office-interop, office-js

I have Word Add-in that is run in Windows Word 2016. This Add-in must use 
`Office.context.document.getFileAsync` function from OfficeJs - to get and process all document content on a server side.

**Issue:** But sometimes I need to open old .DOC files format, then Word is running in "Compatibility Mode" and this function is **failed**.

**Question:** Can I somehow convert it to ".DOCX"format on the client side - using officejs? Or at least send ".doc" file as is, mean get a raw binary of file and send to server?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add-ins built with Office.js do not run on legacy file types such as `.doc`, `.xls`, or `.ppt`. You would need to convert the files to the new format first.

-Michael, PM for Office add-ins

Comment: Thanks @michael-saunders for your response! But I can run my Add-in in Word 2016, just .doc open file and do all actions on it, but this function failed to run Office.context.document.getFileAsync.  

**Anyway**, I have next question - I was able to get OOXML data from .DOC file by using `Office.context.document.getSelectedDataAsync(Office.CoercionType.OOXML,`. 
But I can't find how I can select all data :(( 
Can you suggest how I can select all text/document using OfficeJs?

Thanks!

Comment: If you're able to trigger add-ins through ribbon buttons in `.doc` files, that's a bug that we're working to fix: legacy file types aren't supported unfortunately. If you depend on working specifically with legacy file types and cannot convert them, you should not use add-ins built with Office.js.

Comment: got it! Thanks for your help! Btw, where I can submit a bug and take my money? :D, it's a joke

Comment: @MichaelSaunders we have a .doc that does not disable the officejs addin ribbon buttons. I think this could be because the doc is read only... Should I log it as a bug?